# how to invoke gnuplot application from command prompt screen in windows ??

Tags: cmd, gnuplot

I have downloaded Gnuplot application in windows, On running the application it gives it's own command screen. But if I try to invoke it in Command prompt screen of windows, it says

*"gnuplot is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file."*

Can anyone please tell me **how to invoke gnuplot application from command prompt screen in windows**!!

Note: And also this is the reason if I am trying to invoke gnuplot from within a C program, on compilation through cmd terminal though it gives no error but still I get no display output. (may be).

Answer (score 1):

It opens fine from the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin> gnuplot.exe

        G N U P L O T
        Version 4.6 patchlevel 0    last modified 2012-03-04
        Build System: MS-Windows 32 bit

        Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2012
        Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

        gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
        faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
        immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

gnuplot changed the codepage of this console from 437 to 1252 to
match the graph window. Some characters might only display correctly
if you change the font to a non-raster type.

Terminal type set to 'windows'
gnuplot>
```

If you have a gnuplot script (say scr.gnuplot) just run it as : `gnuplot.exe scr.gnuplot` from the "C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin" folder.

Comment: This is it I reached here supplying the path to cmd, but if i try to run command like  "gnuplot -p -e \"plot '/home/user/Desktop/program/O_Spectra.txt'\""

Comment: @user3185742 You must have the directory with the `gnuplot.exe` binary in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: I already did it in Environment variables settings, but may be still something is missing.